# How do I access records from a 2 level nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have 3 models User,Listing and Message. What I want is for an authenticated user to have many listings. The listings then can have multiple messages. So the messages are tied to the user through the listing model. I am able to get a users listings but not able to get the users messages which he owns through the listings. Here are the associations that I currently have.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :listings, :dependent => :destroy
end
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :messages
end
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :listing
end
```

To create a message I simply do this;

```
@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
@message = @listing.messages.build(params[:message])
```

And getting the user's listing i have this;

```
@user_listings = Listing.user_listings(current_user)
```

But getting the messages tied to the user's listings proves to be elusive. What am I doing wrong or how do I go about this? help appreciated.

Comment: Where does user_listings come into this?

Comment: mark, that's because there's no way of getting the messages unless you get the users listings. The message model is a grandchild of the User model though there is no direct association between the two models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure where user_listings comes from but why not this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id], :include => {:listings => :messages})

@user.listings.each do |listing|
  listing.messages.each do |message|

#or 

@user.listings.collect(&:messages).each do |message|

#or (just read about using authenticated user so the same as above like this

current_user.listings(:all, :include => :messages)...
```

Include prefetches all the listings' associated messages in one query in order that they're not fetched in the loop causing n+1 querying.

```
----------
```

Or another approach, if you don't need the listings data.

```
#messages.rb

   def self.user_messages user_id
     find(:all, :joins => :listings, :conditions => ["listings.user_id = ?", user_id])

   #with pagination

   def self.user_messages user_id, page
     paginate(:all, :joins => :listings, 
                    :conditions => ["listings.user_id = ?", user_id],
                    :per_page => 10, :page => page)
```

Comment: thanks mark, that was very helpful and yes you are right I don't need user_listings.

Comment: You're welcome. Note I've made a correction to the join demonstration to make it a class method rather than of an instance (self.user_m...)

Answer (score 0):

updated regarding your comment.

You may want to just add has_many :messages to the user class as well and add a user_id column to Message.  Then you could just do `current_user.messages`

Comment: Thanks re5et but that's not really what I want. That is getting messages tied to just 1 listing. What I want is get all messages linked to all listings owned by that user.

Comment: re5et, would that make it redundant for both the Listing and Message to have a user id.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :listing_messages, :through => :listings
```

That way you dont have to "tie" the messages with the user because it is always accessed through the listing association:

```
current_user.listing_messages.all
```

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have current_user pulled already. You can just access listings directly by calling

**current_user.listings**

instead of

**@user_listings = Listing.user_listings(current_user)**